# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac and AnnotationProcessorDetector

Tags: android-studio, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not create service of type AnnotationProcessorDetector using JavaGradleScopeServices.createAnnotationProcessorDetector().
> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 10s

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in app level build.gradle in android block.

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```